# How to pass a list elements alternately to some function in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a file in which there are few lines and from python script i am reading the file line by line. File look like following:

```
    - Correct reference to JKLR45, fixed file
    - Xyz changes being done in file
    - Hello welcone
```

The script is as follows:

```
    f =open('change_log.txt', 'r')
    first_line = f.readlines() 
    for i in range(len(first_line )):
                print first_line [i]
```

The otput of above script is as follows:

```
    - Correct reference to JKLR45, fixed file
    - Xyz changes being done in file
    - Hello welcone
```

Now i want to pass this output to other function but i am not getting how to pass the output to function. i tried as follows:

```
def function(*value):
     print value
def read_file():
    f =open('change_log.txt', 'r')
    first_line = f.readlines() 
    for i in range(len(first_line )):
                print first_line [i]
                function(*first_line [i])
```

but i get output of function(*value) as follows:

```
 ['-','C','o','r','r','e','t'.........]
```

But i dont want this kind of output out of function(*value) rather i want it to print:

```
    - Correct reference to JKLR45, fixed file
    - Xyz changes being done in file
    - Hello welcone
```

So, please suggest how shall this be achieved?

Comment: Remove the the star before `value` and `first_line`, and it should work as intended. By the way, naming the variable `first_line` is misleading as it contains a list of all lines. You should rather call it `lines` or something like that.

Comment: What's more, a more pythonic way to iterate over lists is `for something in your_list:`

Answer (score 0):

You could try deleting the asterix in

```
def function(*value):
```

and

```
function(*first_line [i])
```

Which is not required in your example.

That splits the argument given to the function for processing and usually used when the number of arguments that will be passed into the function is not certain. Or like this:

```
def func(a, b, c):
    #process
    return #anything

x = (arg1, arg2, arg3)
print func(*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the `*`. Here is a bit improved version:

```
def function(value):
     print value,

def read_file():
    with open('change_log.txt', 'r') as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            function(line)

read_file()
```

`with open()` opens the file with the promise to close it as soon as you dedent. You can iterate directly over the open file object `fobj`. No need for `range` and indexing with `i`. Call the function with `value`. Using `*value` means to hand all elements of your line as separate argument to `function`. Finally, `print value,` the trailing comma suppresses the newline from `print` because there is already one from the file content.

Answer (score 0):

You should define like this,

```
def function(value):
     print value
```

See [function definitions](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions)

> A function call always assigns values to all parameters mentioned in
>   the parameter list, either from position arguments, from keyword
>   arguments, or from default values. If the form `*identifier` is
>   present, it is initialized to a tuple receiving any excess positional
>   parameters, defaulting to the empty tuple. If the form `**identifier`
>   is present, it is initialized to a new dictionary receiving any excess
>   keyword arguments, defaulting to a new empty dictionary.